# JGraphT Image Creation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jgrapht

I need to create an Directed Graph and an image displaying this Graph.

I tried using [DirectedGraph](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/DirectedGraph.html) which works just fine to create the Graph, it´s internally stored correctly, I tested this but I fail in creating an image from it to Display in an E4 RCP Application.

This is my code:

```
import org.jgraph.JGraph;
import org.jgrapht.DirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.ext.JGraphModelAdapter;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultDirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;

DirectedGraph <String, DefaultEdge> graph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
addVertexes();
addEdges();

//Create image from graph 
JGraphModelAdapter<String, DefaultEdge> graphModel = new JGraphModelAdapter<String, DefaultEdge>(graph);
JGraph jgraph = new JGraph (graphModel);
BufferedImage img = jgraph.getImage(Color.WHITE, 5);
```

but apparently img is always null. Why is that so and how can I change this to work properly?

Answer (score 2):

Just read about JGraphX and tried using that, so for me it works just fine! This is an example of my code now (example with reduced Vertices and Edges).

```
mxGraph graphMx = new mxGraph();

graphMx.insertVertex(graphMx.getDefaultParent(), "Start", "Start", 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 30.0, "rounded");
graphMx.insertVertex(graphMx.getDefaultParent(), "Ende", "Ende", 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 30.0, "rounded");

graphMx.insertEdge(graphMx.getDefaultParent(), null, "", ((mxGraphModel)graphMx.getModel()).getCell("Start"), ((mxGraphModel)graphMx.getModel()).getCell("Ende"));

mxIGraphLayout layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graphMx);
layout.execute(graphMx.getDefaultParent());

BufferedImage image = mxCellRenderer.createBufferedImage(graphMx, null, 1, Color.WHITE, true, null);
return image;
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is similar to @HexFlex, but i got this to work the same way, although i'm not sure how to customize the drawing:

```java
String GRAPH_FILE_PATH = "somwhere/u/want.png";

public static <V, E> File drawGraph(Graph<V, E> graph) throws IOException {
    JGraphXAdapter<V, E> graphAdapter = new JGraphXAdapter<V, E>(graph);
    mxIGraphLayout layout = new mxCircleLayout(graphAdapter);
    layout.execute(graphAdapter.getDefaultParent());
    BufferedImage image = mxCellRenderer.createBufferedImage(graphAdapter, null, 2, new Color(0f,0f,0f,.5f), true, null);
    File imgFile = new File(GRAPH_FILE_PATH);
    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", imgFile);
    return imgFile;
}
```

Edit:
Btw, the code is from https://www.baeldung.com/jgrapht, i just refactored it into a function

Answer (score 0):

you can also put it on a JFRAME and generate an image from that frame.
-Jan